# Android room SELECT * WHERE returns all records

Tags: java, android

I've got an Android Room database setup and followed some tutorials with which I'm trying to extend what I've made. I have gotten a few queries to work but when I try to use a `SELECT * WHERE` query it returns all the records in the table not just the records with the expected ID.

The Query in the DAO

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM weapon_table WHERE fighter_id = :fighter_id" )
LiveData<List<Weapon>> getFighterWeapons(long fighter_id);
```

The Record Object

```
@Entity(tableName = "weapon_table",
        foreignKeys = {
                @ForeignKey(entity = com.Database.Fighter.class,
                        parentColumns = "fighter_id",
                        childColumns = "fighter_id"),
        })
public class Weapon
{
    @NonNull
    String weapon_name;
    @NonNull
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    long weapon_id;
    @NonNull
    long fighter_id;


    public Weapon(String weapon_name, long fighter_id)
    {
        this.weapon_name = weapon_name;
        this.fighter_id = fighter_id;
    }

    public long getWeapon_id()
    {
        return weapon_id;
    }

    public void setWeapon_id(long weapon_id)
    {
        this.weapon_id = weapon_id;
    }

    public String getWeapon_name()
    {
        return weapon_name;
    }

    public void setWeapon_name(String weapon_name)
    {
        this.weapon_name = weapon_name;
    }

    public long getFighter_id()
    {
        return fighter_id;
    }

    public void setFighter_id(long fighter_id)
    {
        this.fighter_id = fighter_id;
    }
}
```

When I call the following code all records are printed to the debug console but the current ID is also printed and stays the same in all cases.

```
   public void onClickAddWeapon(View view)
{
    List<Weapon> weapons = mWeaponViewModel.getFighterWeapons(fighter.getFighter_id()).getValue();
    for(Weapon weapon: weapons )
    {
        Log.d("WEAPONDEBUG", "WEAPONNAME/ID: " +weapon.getWeapon_name() +'/'+ weapon.getFighter_id() );
        Log.d("WEAPONDEBUG", "FIGHTERID: "+ fighter.getFighter_id() );

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fix was fairly simple , I had followed this [google code labs tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#7) and when I tried to extend it I forgot to actually assign the result of the query to the list held in the repository file. Thanks for the suggestions they put me in the right direction.

```
  LiveData<List<Weapon>> getFighterWeapons(long fighter_id)
    {
        mWeaponDao.getFighterWeapons(fighter_id);
        return mAllWeapons;
    }
```

replaced with

```
LiveData<List<Weapon>> getFighterWeapons(long fighter_id)
{
    mAllWeapons = mWeaponDao.getFighterWeapons(fighter_id);
    return mAllWeapons;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your code should be working, but I think that the problem is defining with foreign keys. `

```
parentColumns = "fighter_id",
```

`childColumns = "fighter_id"`

can you remove it and try?

```
                    `
```

Comment: I've removed the foreign keys but still no luck

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM weapon_table WHERE fighter_id IN (:fighter_id)" )
LiveData<List<Weapon>> getFighterWeapons(long fighter_id);
```

Comment: It's still giving me all the records

Comment: insert a record for different fighter_id and then check

Comment: I've inserted both another weapon_id and a different fighter_id but still no luck

Comment: While this results in a valid SQL query, it's bad since a simple `=` exists for this exact reason.